# try catch placement issue within program design?

Tags: java, try-catch

I've put in the try catch as shown now the program still skips to the 2nd & 3rd input question without printing the error exception after ("Enter your operation: add, subtract, divide, multiply, or exit"). Also if "exit" is inputed for first question the the 2nd & 3rd input requirements still loop before program finishes, is there any way to exit immediately as prompted with the other inputs being required?
Any suggestions welcome

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;


 class Monday {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double n1,n2;
    boolean check = true;

    while(check) {
        System.out.println("Enter your operation: add, subtract, divide, multiply, or exit");
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String op = myScan.next();
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter your 1st number");
            try {
                n1 = myScan.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter your 2nd number");
                n2 = myScan.nextDouble();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("This is my error");
                return;
            }

         /* System.out.println("Enter your 1st number");
            n1 = myScan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter your 2nd number");
            n2 = myScan.nextDouble();*/




            switch (op) {
                case"add":
                System.out.println("Your answer is "+ (n1 + n2));
                break;

                case"subtract":
                System.out.println("Your answer is "+ (n1 - n2));
                break;

                case"divide":
                System.out.println("Your answer is "+ (n1 / n2));
                break;

                case"multiply":
                System.out.println("Your answer is "+ (n1 * n2)) ;
                break;

                case"exit":
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                break;

            }


            if ("exit".equals(op))
            check = false;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("This is my error");

            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need try/catch.

```
double n1, n2;
System.out.println("Enter your 1st number");
if (myScan.hasNextDouble()) n1 = myScan.nextDouble();
else return;
System.out.println("Enter your 2nd number");
if (myScan.hasNextDouble()) n2 = myScan.nextDouble();
else return;
```

But if you want to use it:

```
double n1, n2;
System.out.println("Enter your 1st number");
try {
    n1 = myScan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter your 2nd number");
    n2 = myScan.nextDouble();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("This is my error");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Sorry not explaining myself very well, I want the program to give an error if I don't input the right operator after the first question "System.out.println("Enter your operation: add, subtract, divide, multiply, or exit");" and if exit is inputted to have the program end without asking the further questions.

Comment: Thanks for that, but will this not affect the switch statement below, and the loop ? won't compile as "String op" is no longer recognised.

Comment: I've put in the try catch as shown now the program still skips to the 2nd & 3rd input question without printing the error exception after ("Enter your operation: add, subtract, divide, multiply, or exit"). Also if "exit" is inputed for first question the the 2nd & 3rd input requirements still loop before program finishes, is there any way to exit immediately as prompted with the other inputs being required? Any suggestions welcome

Comment: System.exit(1) is how to exit

Comment: Thanks, I'm an absolute novice here so unfortunately that means nothing to me. Really appreciated the help though. I'll go back to the start and design it better I think.

Comment: Just put "System.exit(1);" (copy and paste that line, except for the quotes) at the end of the catch block.  It will exit the program.

Comment: Thanks but it has no effect for me, I'm no doubt trying your patience at this stage. it still loops through both questions and no error message is printed if there is an erroneous first input other than those specified.